# How to Version control and Configuration Management in Oracle APEX 4.2

Tags: oracle, svn, oracle-apex, configuration-management

I have two oracle apex applications deployed in several geographic locations. And I want to merge them together as one baseline code-base and using configuration management like process to deploy the application in both locations functionality wise. How am I going to achieve this in Oracle apex. And I want to use the version control in APEX also.

Thanks,
Thusira.

Comment: The simple answer, unfortunately, is there is no automatic, reliable, merge capability for Apex applications. You have to find the differences and manually make the changes in your baseline yourself.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use following link
it seems that it is a tool for comparing applications
Application Builder-> Cross Application Reports -> Application Comparison

Comment: i am not trying to compare the application. Assume i have the whole application with me and want to deliver the application functionality wise to   both locations. Need to figure it out how can i perform such configuration management with SVN .

Comment: as i know advanced apex developers use SQLDeveloper for managing their applications and SQL developer supports svn and subversioning it may solve your need